# SAP CAP Service Deployment to Cloud Foundry Fails with "CRASHED" Status and "Exited with Status 1" Error

Tags: node.js, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cap

I am encountering an issue while trying to deploy a SAP Cloud Application Programming Model (CAP) service to Cloud Foundry from my local machine. The deployment process fails with the following error message:

[PollStartAppStatusExecution] [my-bookshop] c6f73a09-978a-4506-b8da-2b8cb8c28737 [2023-12-18T06:26:47.222916] App instance exited with guid c6f73a09-978a-4506-b8da-2b8cb8c28737 payload: {"instance"=>"80b21fc9-8954-418c-4149-6777", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"0e9d359d-cbb1-42e2-ae1d-5cfbdc4910b6", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1702880807193484225, "version"=>"1fe88744-4a0c-4913-a5f1-5de8c046f2c1"} (STDOUT, API)#

This indicates that the application instance crashed with a status of 1 during deployment. I have already checked the logs, but the information provided is not sufficient to pinpoint the root cause of the issue.

Here are some additional details:

- "@sap/cds": "^7"
- Cloud Foundry CLI version: 7.7.5+cb1adea.2023-11-20
- Node.js version: v20.10.0
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04

I have tried to review the application logs and the deployment process, but I couldn't find any specific errors or issues leading to the crash. Has anyone encountered a similar problem during SAP CAP service deployment to Cloud Foundry?

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!